# Python 3.11 : ImportError: cannot import name 'Pipeline' from 'pyannote.audio'

Tags: python-3.x

I'm becoming crazy with the
I'm coding on Thonny, an IDE for python.
I followed the install step to install pyannote.audio :
`pip install -qq https://github.com/pyannote/pyannote-audio/archive/refs/heads/develop.zip`

I don't manage to import Pipeline from pyannote.audio. I get this error :
`ImportError: cannot import name 'Pipeline' from 'pyannote.audio'`

I'm not blind, I can see that the author of the library capitalizes the P in Pipeline to call the function. I respect the capitalization.

I'm working on Windows 10.

I tried on IDE directly, it doesn't work either (with the same message). I am stuck and I don't see how to solve this problem. There are only two topics on a forum about this problem, but no solution.

I checked my "site-packages" folder, the pyannote packages are there. I have uninstalled and reinstalled several times with pip requests. I'm running out of solutions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue (Windows 10, Python 3.11.3) and I found it was a result of pip installing an earlier, non-compatible version of pyannote.audio.

`pip show pyannote.audio` => `Version: 1.1.2`

I was able to install the newest version directly from the [git repo](https://github.com/pyannote/pyannote-audio)

`# install from develop branch pip install -qq https://github.com/pyannote/pyannote-audio/archive/refs/heads/develop.zip`

Good luck!